# Editing theme files and access to the Code pages only to super-admin?

Tags: themes, multisite, plugin-recommendation, customization

When I deal with Multisite installation.Some themes like mystique and aparatus provide the widget areas with in the theme-settings page to enter Advertising codes in the form of HTML or java script .But I want the 'Ad code Boxes' to access only by super admin(Me on my Multisite) and not by Normal admins .Can I make that boxes available only to me?

Comment: Please mark any of the answers as an answer. I think both are correct, it depends on your theme(s) and can not be generally answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is custom functionality in theme options page then it is highly specific to that theme. Likely you will need to edit theme files and/or create child theme. Plus option pages can be simply in WordPress API but just as well can be built with help of theme framework or other kind of third party code.

I think your first stop should be developers of themes and information on how to best work with their option pages.

Answer (score 1):

If a widget/feature is built in a theme, you can't specify it's access right to particular user. As long as the admins can use the theme, they can use the widget.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Capabilities plugin - [Capability Manager (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/) . You can give finer grained access to existing or new roles than you can with the default roles.

Comment: Do you mean the Capability Manager Plugin? - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/

Comment: I think that's the one. It has a different name in Wordpress after you download it.

Comment: please share your link to the one you mean.

Comment: @hakre: Yes, that link you shared above was the one I had used http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman